# How to summon an item frame with a custom name item in it? [1.14]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'd like help with a certain command that spawns an 'item_frame' with an item that has a tag in it. I have already tried:

```
/summon minecraft:item_frame ~ ~ ~ {Facing:1,Item:{id:"minecraft:melon_seeds",Damage:5,Count:1,tag:{dysplay:{Name:"Bullets"}}}}
```

It works, but it gives me the item with the tag of its name on it, even if I typed "Bullets". Before I started the command I gave to myself 6 Melon Seeds:

[image]

The new Melon Seeds should be named "Bullets", but they are named "Melon Seeds" because they won't even stack in the 1# slot, it still says 6:

[image]

If I did something wrong, can you please tell me where is my mistake? If I did everything the right way, can you please tell me another command on how I can summon an item frame with a custom name item in it?

Comment: Hi MrTundy, welcome to Arqade! Going by your original post and your commands, it appears you have a bit of difficulty determining when to use 'y' and when to use 'i'. The first thing you might want to try is replacing 'dysplay` with 'display' in your command and see what you get from there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, but the error is always the same, isn't there another type of command that i can use instead?Thank you for the help.

Comment: What I immediately noticed, without trying anything: "Damage" is not a thing inside the item NBT directly, it has to go in "tag". And it might also be called differently, I'm not sure. And "dysplay" is of course wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same, but I also wanted to place the item in an invisible frame. Combining the first two answers above with some other research, I ended up making this `.mcfunction` file:

```
# summon a frame with a named item in it
summon minecraft:item_frame -2633 -8 2825 {Facing:1b,Item:{id:"minecraft:red_dye",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"My Custom Name"}'}}}, Tags: ["your_unique_tag_name"]}

# turn it invisible
data merge entity @e[tag=your_unique_tag_name,limit=1] {Invisible:1b}
```

It took two steps to get the invisibility to work, but the end result is nice. Just set your own coordinates, `minecraft:item-name`, and pick any value for `your_unique_tag_name` and you should be good to go.

This was done in 1.18.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
/summon item_frame ~ ~ ~ {Facing:1,Item:{id:"minecraft:melon_seeds",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:Bullets}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem in 1.16 the solution is using `Name:'{"text":"nameHere"}'` tag and put the command in a command block it will work. for no reason if you don't put the command in a command block it won't work.